# Aplicar limite para una condición

Tags: postgresql

Tengo una consulta que me devuelve las notas crédito (CN) y las notas débito (DN) de una operación, cada CN está acompañada de dos o más DN, en el momento de paginar, por ejemplo debo traer 10 operaciones es decir 10 CN y sus respectivas DN, pero si dejo el límite en 10, éste también contará las notas débito de la operación que debo retornar en la consulta. Es decir sólo me traerá 2, 3 o 4 operaciones dependiendo del número de DN que acompañen la nota crédito.

```
SELECT
    value, installment, payment_plan_id, model,
    creation_date, operation 
    FROM payment_plant
    WHERE model != 'IMMEDIATE'
    AND operation IN ('CN', 'DN')
    AND creation_date BETWEEN '2017-06-12' AND '2017-07-12 23:59:59'
ORDER BY
    model,
    creation_date,
    operation 
LIMIT 10
OFFSET 1
```

Ejemplo de la tabla obviando algunos campos:

```
| id | payment_plan_id | value | installment | operation |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | b3cdaede        | 12    | 1           | NC        |
| 2  | b3cdaede        | 3.5   | 1           | ND        |
| 3  | b3cdaede        | 1.2   | 1           | ND        |
| 4  | e1d7f051        | 36    | 1           | NC        |
| 5  | e1d7f051        | 5.9   | 1           | ND        |
| 6  | 00e6a0b4        | 15    | 1           | NC        |
| 7  | 00e6a0b4        | 1     | 1           | ND        |
| 8  | 00e6a0b4        | 3.6   | 1           | ND        |
```

¿Cómo puedo limitar que el Límite para que sólo tenga en cuenta las CN?

Comment: El diseño no parece correcto. Cómo sabes qué DN están asociadas a un particular CN?

Comment: Olvidé agregar que están referenciadas por otro campo que se llama `payment_plan_id`.

Comment: No se entiende. payment_plant_id no es la clave primaria de payment_plant ? Por favor, especifica bien como es la tabla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes hacer eso directamente. El LIMIT es por registros (filas resultantes de la consulta). Una alternativa que se me ocurre es:

```
SELECT
    value, installment, payment_plan_id, model,
    creation_date, operation 
    FROM payment_plant
    WHERE model != 'IMMEDIATE'
    AND operation IN ('CN', 'DN')
    AND payment_plan_id IN
    (
       SELECT
       payment_plan_id
       FROM payment_plant
       WHERE model != 'IMMEDIATE'
       AND operation = 'CN'
       AND creation_date BETWEEN '2017-06-12' AND '2017-07-12 23:59:59'
       ORDER BY
       model, creation_date,
       LIMIT 10
       OFFSET 1
    )
  ORDER BY
     model, creation_date, operation
```

Es decir, primero buscas los CN, limitados a la pagina correspondiente y traes sus `payment_plan_id`. Luego traes todos los CN/DN que corresponden a esos `payment_plan_id`.

Claro que esto requiere que efectivamente cada `payment_plan_id` corresponda a un solo CN. Y para ser eficiente `payment_plan_id` debe estar indexado.

Comment: Gracias, funcionó correctamente. Ahora tengo otra duda, cómo puedo retornar un `count()` sólo de los que cumplen la condición ('CN'), sin hacer una consulta similar. ¿Es posible ponerle condiciones al `count`?

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. Podrías editar el ejemplo?

Comment: Hecho, agregué el `count`. Sin embargo haciéndolo de esta manera me pide usar `GROUP BY`

Comment: `count(operacion) filter (where operacion = 'CN') as total_count`